# How to get the last succesful build number from Code Build through Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create a Docker image where the tag is going to be the last succesful build number, and I cannot seem to find a way to doing so.

This is my script

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "tf_codebuild_project" {
  name          = var.aws_project_name
  description   = var.aws_project_name
  build_timeout = "60"

  service_role  = var.aws_codebuild_role_arn

  source {
    type            = "CODECOMMIT"
    location        = var.aws_codecommit_repo_url
    buildspec       = "buildspec.yml"
    git_clone_depth = 1
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "NO_ARTIFACTS" 
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/standard:4.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"

    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html
    environment_variable {
      name  = "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
      value = var.aws_default_region
    }

    environment_variable {
      name  = "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID"
      value = var.aws_account_id
    }

    environment_variable {
      name  = "IMAGE_NAME"
      value = var.aws_codecommit_repo_name
    }

    environment_variable {
      name  = "IMAGE_TAG"
      value = "${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
  }

  tags = var.aws_codebuild_tags
}
```

And this is what I'm getting

```
> 
> Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
> │
> on modules\codebuild\main.tf line 50, in resource "aws_codebuild_project" "tf_codebuild_project":
> 50:       value = "${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}"
> │
> An input variable with the name "CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER" {} block.
```

So the issue is with this:

```
environment_variable {
  name  = "IMAGE_TAG"
  value = "${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}"
}
```

Comment: So it has to be this variable `${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}`? It is available within a CodeBuild run?

Comment: yes, it is a CodeBuild variable > https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work you have to use double $$ sign, i.e:

```
environment_variable {
  name  = "IMAGE_TAG"
  value = "$${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}"
}
```

This is per terraform's [escape sequences](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences):

> `$${` | Literal `${`, without beginning an interpolation sequence.

This way, terraform will not try to look for a variable and it will pass it to CodeBuild as `${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}`.